# Macports error when trying to select "open-mp-fortan" for "mpi"

Tags: macports

When running the command `sudo port select mpi openmpi-mp-fortan` I receive the following error:

> Selecting 'openmpi-mp-fortan' for 'mpi' failed: The specified version 'openmpi-mp-fortan' is not valid.

When I list the available versions for mpi via `port select --list mpi` I receive the following output:

> Available versions for mpi:
>       
>      none
>       
>      openmpi-mp (active)

What's going on here? Why is `openmpi-mp-fortan` not listed as a version for mpi? I am following the install instructions for the Einstein Toolkit found at  [this link](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/nds-org/jupyter-et/blob/master/CactusTutorial.ipynb) , and I have been trying to fix this issue for a little over a week now. I have been attempting to learn how to use macports but am still very unfamiliar. Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be due to the update of the default gcc in macports to gcc9 since the Einstein Toolkit instructions were written.

Installing gcc9 and forcing openmpi-gcc9 using

```
sudo port uninstall gcc8
sudo port install gcc9
sudo port install openmpi-gcc9
```

instead fixes the issue and provides a

```
sudo port select --set mpi openmpi-gcc9-fortran
```

option to select the working Fortran variant of OpenMPI.

Comment: This issue now appears to be resolved.  With the latest macports (2019-11-07) openmpi-mp-fortan is now an option for port select --set mpi.